# Не могу запустить node.js приложение, кроме как через visual studio

Tags: node.js, cmd, node-modules

Создал простое приложение, в visual studio всё запускается и работает. Но запускаю через CMD консоль командой node server.js и вылетает ошибка:

```
O:\Node\dataManipulaion\dataManipulaion>node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'O:\Node\dataManipulaion\dataManipulaion\server.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Установленные модули (их устанавливал через npm visual studio):

- express 4.17.1
- path 0.12.7
- socket.io 2.3.0

Код server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var maxMessages = 40;
var messages = [];

app.use(require('express').static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        if (!msg.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
            console.log('sended only spaces');
        }
        else {
            messages.push(msg);
            if (messages.length > maxMessages) {
                messages.shift()
            }

            io.emit('chat message', msg);
            console.log(messages);
        }
    });
    socket.on('chat getMessages', () => {
        if (messages.length > maxMessages) {
            messages.shift()
        }

        io.emit('chat sendMessages', messages);
    });
});

http.listen(1337, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:1337');
});
```

Структура файлов через cmd dir:

```
    O:\Node\dataManipulaion\dataManipulaion>dir
 Том в устройстве O имеет метку Projects
 Серийный номер тома: 201A-816B

 Содержимое папки O:\Node\dataManipulaion\dataManipulaion

Чт 22.10.20  21:58    <DIR>          .
Чт 22.10.20  21:58    <DIR>          ..
Пт 23.10.20  20:25    <DIR>          dataManipulaion
Чт 22.10.20  21:58             1 151 dataManipulaion.sln
               1 файлов          1 151 байт
               3 папок  50 469 253 120 байт свободно
```

Comment: Покажите структуру файлов пожалуйста, через cmd dir

Comment: @твойкот добавил в вопрос

Comment: У вас же здесь нет server.js файла

Comment: Мда, видимо в час ночи плохая идея что то делать, вообщем сам уже увидел и исправил: просто дериктория не та, да ещё и 2 сервера вместе запустил.